# Execute a callback if the value in the element changes

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Let's say I'm running a linear regression on a couple of dependent variable(`d1`, `d2`, `d3`) to predict an independent variable(`id`) on a stream of data.

```
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Interval(id='data-stream', interval=1000, n_intervals=0),
    html.Div(id='count'),
    html.Div(id='betas'),
])

@app.callback(
    Output('count', 'children'),
    [Input('data-stream', 'n_intervals')]
)
def get_count(data):
    df = pd.read_csv(*some url that updates and returns a csv*)
    count = len(df['id'])
    return html.H2(f'The count is {count}')

@app.callback(
    Output('betas', 'children'),
    [*what goes in here?*]
)
def run_regression(*arg_inputs):
    # Run Regression here that outputs a table of betas
```

How do I make a callback (to run the regression) whenever the count changes value i.e. `html.Div(id='count')` instead of being dependent on the Interval???

I've looked at documentations for `Event` and even tried doing `Input('count', 'children')` as the `inputs` argument for the callback decorator to the `run_regression` function, and it still streamed rather than the regression being re-run when the count of observation changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your input should be the `count` you can use for that something like that

```
@app.callback(
    Output('betas', 'children'),
    Input('count','value')
)
def run_regression(count_value):
    # Run Regression here that outputs a table of betas
```

Here your input is like you mentioned the length of count so you can use it to do what you want (to be sure you can add a print inside your function run_regression to print count_value to see what it is looks like)
If you need more help you should explain what your run_regression function supposed do ;)